# Dynamic website scraping using Nightmare

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I am trying to scrap Google search using Nightmare.js(for Node.js) . I am basically searching for a word (I don't want to go to Google home page and navigate from there as the input will be set of predefined URLs) and taking a screenshot for it. Since google search is dynamically loaded by javascripts, I am having trouble and my screenshots are blank. Can anyone point the issue?
This is the code I use.

```
//nightmarte
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');

var google = new Nightmare()
  .viewport(1000, 1000)
  .useragent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36")
  .goto('https://www.google.com/#q=barak%20obama&rct=j')
  .wait()
  .screenshot('obama.png')
  .run(function(err, nightmare) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('Done!');
  });
```

Comment: I guess `wait()` misses an argument. Either a duration in ms, or a selector which will be checked for presence.

Comment: I tried giving a selector but the problem is that, it is also generated through javascript. The HTML I get from this script has only Javascript. I think, once I get the rendered HTML, then it should work.

Comment: What version of Nightmare are you using?